# Is the Cartesian product calculation of multiple resource lists suitable for flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-batch

I have a Cartesian product of a list of resources A and a list of resources B and each combination will calculate the score and finally sort this scenario Is flink applicable?
My intention is to have these computations distributed across machines and get results very quickly

Comment: This sounds like a join, perhaps with an aggregation, and then a sort. Is that right? If so, sure, Flink can do that, but if you require a global sort of the results then that can't be done in parallel.